# How to define a default tooltip style for all Controls

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I would like to define a style with a template when there are validation errors and would display the first error message as a tooltip.

It works fine when targeting specific control like DatePicker in the following xaml.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolKit:DatePicker}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" 
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                    Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I cannot get it to work for Control though, i.e. the following doesn't give any tooltip

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolKit:Control}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" 
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                    Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you create a `Behavior` for this one.

Every control is unique in itself and this is not a reliable way to attach a specific behavior to all controls. And in fact, you may end up setting this property on unwanted controls that don't even require validation.

`Behaviors` are clean and you can assign them to selected controls only. `Attached Properties` or a `Master Behavior` can be used to assign `Behaviors` to child controls.

Here is a [CodeProject article from Josh Smith](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AttachedBehaviors.aspx) to get you started on `Behaviors`.